# Subtraction with carry of positive numbers

Tags: haskell

Given two lists of digits such as `[1, 2, 0] = 120` and `[1,0,1] = 101`, my function `sub` should return the list `[1, 9] = 19` but the function is returning `[2, -1]` instead. How do I solve this carry problem? It works fine when there isn't a carry and it only receives positive numbers.
Here's the code I have:

```
sub_Carry :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sub_Carry c x []
            | c == 0 = x
            | otherwise = sub_Carry 0 [c] x
sub_Carry c [] x
            | c == 0 = x
            | otherwise = sub_Carry 0 x [c]
sub_Carry c (x : xs) (y : ys) = (x - y) : sub_Carry c xs ys

sub :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sub op1 op2
       | to_Integer(op1) == to_Integer(op2) = [0]
       | to_Integer(op1) > to_Integer(op2) = drop_Zeros (reverse (sub_Carry 0 (reverse op1) (reverse op2)))
       | otherwise = [-1] ++ drop_Zeros (reverse (sub_Carry 0 (reverse op1) (reverse op2)))
```

Other considerations:

- I've have other utility functions such as `to_Integer` that converts the list into it's correspondent integer, `drop_Zeros` that removes zeros to the right of the list (`[0, 1, 0] = [1, 0]`)
- in the case the result is a negative number it should return the list with -1 at the head (`[1, 0, 0] - [1, 0, 1] = [-1, 1]`)

Comment: How about you convert to an integer, subtract, convert back to a list?

Comment: 1. It is customary to write `to_Integer(op1)` as `toInteger op1`. 2. `sub_Carry c x [] | c == 0 = x` should be written as `subCarry 0 x [] = x`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann the exercise is to do the long addiction and subtraction with carry. I've got the long addiction function done but I'm having trouble with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you don't use the parameter `c` for carrying. It is the central point of the exercise. It is also necessary to solve the case when the list of a parameter `y` ends earlier than `x`. My program works only for positive results. So I also modified the function `sub` to reverse parameters when `op1 < op2`. Now there should be always a positive result, which you then negate using the constant -1.

```
sub_Carry :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sub_Carry 0 [] [] = []
sub_Carry c x [] = sub_Carry c x [0]
sub_Carry c (x : xs) (y : ys)
            | (x - y - c) < 0 = (10 + x - y - c) : sub_Carry 1 xs ys
            | otherwise = (x - y - c ) : sub_Carry 0 xs ys

sub :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sub op1 op2
       | to_Integer(op1) == to_Integer(op2) = [0]
       | to_Integer(op1) > to_Integer(op2) = drop_Zeros (reverse (sub_Carry 0 (reverse op1) (reverse op2)))
       | otherwise = [-1] ++ drop_Zeros (reverse (sub_Carry 0 (reverse op2) (reverse op1)))
```